# Bind jinja2 loop variable to javascript function

Tags: javascript, html, flask, jinja2

I'm attempting to bind a loop variable in Jinja2 to a function, but it is not recognized. Does anyone have suggestions for how to dynamically pass it to a function? Thank you in advance.

```
{% for project in projects.items %}
   <tr>
       <td>{{ project.project_id }}</td>
       <td>{{ project.name }}</td>
       <td>{{ project.external_id }}</td>
       <td>{{ project.company_name | default('', true) }}</td>
       <td>{{ project.company_address | default('', true) }}</td>
       <td>{{ project.company_email | default('', true) }}</td>
       <td>{{ project.company_phone | default('', true) }}</td>
       <td>{{ project.contact_person | default('', true) }}</td>
       <td>{{ project.note | default('', true)}}</td>
       <td>
           <button type="button" id="project-{{ project.id }}" onclick="drawModal.bind(this, '{{ project | tojson }}')" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#edit-modal">
               Edit
           </button>
       </td>
   </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

I also tried `onclick="drawModal.bind(this,{{ project | safe }})"`, but it didn't work either. I even tried including a `script` inside the loop, but it resulted in the same issue.

My goal is to pass `project` to the `drawModal` function so it can fully access the project data.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pretty straightforward method using jQuery. This will allow you to pass your project data to your modal.

Add the project data to a data field of your button:

```html
<button type="button" data-project="{{ project | tojson }}" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#edit-modal">
  Edit
</button>
```

Add a jQuery function to load the data to the modal:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#edit-modal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
    //          make that sure the name here    v   matches the data field in your HTML
    const project = $(e.relatedTarget).data('project')
    // use the JSON object to populate your modal fields
    $(this).find('#modal-project-id').val(project.project_id);
    $(this).find('#modal-project-name').val(project.project_name);
    // etc
  }
}
```